# Running cron job at only specific date and time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

In our express js application have a feature in admin module that he can send mail to users at specific dates (he can able to select a specific date and time).

Say if the date and time is 2018-02-22@12.00  we need to run the email code at that time.

I think this package will full fill our needs https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule,

Here is their documentation

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

But it doesn't say how to run on specific date (year field is missing??) so how do i achieve my need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for specific date, you could use something like following as provided in [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#date-based-scheduling)

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2018, 1, 22, 12, 0, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('job is running');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer one more question do i need to run this cron on separate express js application??

Comment: @iambatman creating a separate file in your express application would be a better option, so that this file only consists your cron related tasks

Comment: Nice. Careful though: the second argument of the months is a zero-based index, i.e. 0 = January, 11 = December. I fell into that pit now...

Comment: thanks . that saved me , i didn't think it was zero based index

Comment: I wont recommend to go with this package, since lets say you schedule job and you restart sever after that, then your job wont run on that time you specified earlier.

Comment: @hardikchugh what package do you recomment?

Comment: Node-cron is fine https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 1):

You can pass date object in it. if you read document further you will find it here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#date-based-scheduling

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
 console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```

Comment: Nice. Careful though: the second argument of the months is a zero-based index, i.e. 0 = January, 11 = December. I fell into that pit now...