# Send mail daily

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I am developing an application where I need to send mail only once daily to the particular persons daily. Is there any concept I should know of in node.js?
I am using angular 8, node.js and SQL server.

Comment: Check `nodemailer` and `node-scheduler`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running cron job at only specific date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274326/running-cron-job-at-only-specific-date-and-time)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node Schedule .
npm install node-schedule

This was a google search away[Link to node-schedule Document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron),The node-cron module is tiny task scheduler in pure JavaScript for node.js based on GNU crontab. This module allows you to schedule task in node.js using full crontab syntax.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0 * * *', function() {
  /*
   * This job runs every day at 12:00:00 AM.
   */
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```